# Laravel - return a redirectResponse selectively generated in a function

Tags: php, laravel

Part of my application is a multi-stage checkout process; during the latter pages of this I first run a sanity check on each request to verify the user actually has some items in their basket: if not they're sent back to the beginning.

I have a controller function like this which is called from multiple routes for [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) purposes.

```
private function checkBasketFull($request)
{
    if (self::isBasketEmpty($request)) {
        return redirect('/')->with('status', config('app.empty_basket_message'));
    }
}
```

When I call it, I can't just do:

```
self::checkBasketFull($request);
```

because without a `return` the redirect doesn't fire, only the session data is sent.

And I can't do:

```
return self::checkBasketFull($request);
```

because that will give an error if there's no redirect or abort the method if  `checkBasketFull` returns anything else.

My current (working) code is:

```
    $check = self::checkBasketFull($request);
    if ($check) {
        return $check;
    }
```

Is there an alternative way of writing this on a single line, or modifying the `checkBasketFull` function, so the redirect will occur if the basket is empty but execution will continue as normal if it isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use this:

```
if ($redirect = self::checkBasketFull($request)) return $redirect;
```

Or throw an error and catch it in the global error handler.

---

However, instead of returning and checking that for a redirect like that, I'd much rather keep it as two completely separate methods:

```
public function someRoute(Request $request)
{
    if ($this->isBasketEmpty($request)) return $this->redirectBasketEmpty();

    // Continue processing this request...
}

protected function isBasketEmpty(request)
{
    // run your login here...
}

protected function redirectBasketEmpty()
{
    return redirect('/')->with('status', config('app.empty_basket_message'));
}
```

Feels cleaner to me.

Comment: Thanks – obvious now I think about it…

Comment: @WilliamTurrell - I'd split them into two methods. See my update.